# Is the face poset of a compact intersection of cylinders and half-spaces shellable?

Tags: co.combinatorics, at.algebraic-topology, discrete-geometry, posets

Let the $n$-disk $D^n$ be stratified hemispherically (so there are two 0-dimensional strata at the poles, two 1-dimensional strata for the prime meridian and the international date line, two 2-dimensional strata for the eastern and western hemisphere, etc). This induces a stratification of the cylinder $D^n \times [-1,1]^m$.

Let $X \subseteq [-1,1]^N$ be the intersection of finitely many cylinders and finitely many half-spaces. I assume that the cylinders and half spaces are obtained via rigid motions from the standard ones, but I'd in fact be happy to make the stronger assumption that the cylinders are all rectilinear (so that $D^n$ is aligned with $n$ of the coordinate axes) of radius 1, centered at the origin, and that the half spaces are all of the form $\{(x_1,\dots,x_N) \mid x_{i_1} \geq x_{i_2} \geq \cdots\}$.

Define a *face* of $X$ to be the intersection with $X$ of some set of strata from the cylinders along with some of the dividing planes for the half-spaces. Then $X$ is a (convex) CW complex, with cells given by the faces.

**Question 1:** Is the face poset of $X$ shellable?

In the case where we use no cylinders but only half-spaces, the answer is well-known to be *yes*. Moreover, in this case, a shelling can be obtained "linearly", by choosing a line passing through the interior of $X$ and incommensurate with the half-planes, and traveling along the line, adding the facets in the order they become visible.

**Question 2:** If the face poset of $X$ is shellable, can a shelling be obtained in the same "linear" way as in the case without cylinders?